# ng-repeater executing every digest cycle

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand how angular 1 digest cycles work and how they impact the existing scope. I have 2 controllers one of them is using angular material with a repeater. The second controller is a simple button click event. Both events print to the console to see what is happening.

What i am seeing is that every time i click the button on the second controller the repeater re-runs its entire calculation?

Is this how angular is intended to work? Please see attached the following codepen - when the button is clicked the repeater re-runs on the first controller every single time. I assume this is going to happen every single time any operations occurs on any controller - which just seems like madness.

the repeater code is as follows:

```
<div flex="50" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)">
            {{ item }} <span ng-if="exists(item, selected)">selected</span>
          </md-checkbox>
        </div>
```

At first i thought there was something wrong in my angular but it seems like this happens anywhere full codepen bellow.

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGXrax)

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. The dirty check cycle runs for the entire app many times until the state of the scope stabilizes. It's an inefficient way of triggering events. But it's also by design - it allows you to work with POJOs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want ng-repeat to rerun on change then use "track by $index" in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

yes this is exactly how it is supposed to work. That is the nature of two-way binding, you constantly check whether one of both values changed.
If you want to turn off that feature and use a one-time binding you can use the :: syntax.

see in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression (you need to scroll down to One-time binding. Sadly there are no anchors :D)